# email_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...).sendForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, email

While I was use the Emailjs to use the email service on my portfolio website.
When i try to submit the form I get this above error..
This was the code that I used to create form, using reactjs..

If someone says about the dependencies then do refer the bellow image

[the email-js dependency that was downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqDEW.jpg)

```
import React from "react";
import "./contact.css";
import { useRef } from "react";
import emailjs from "email-js";

const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service_6kimd8c",
        "template_ql7mhzc",
        form.current,
        "vbCjePCf6E12Qm3kB"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );

    e.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <section className="contact" id="contact">
      <h1 className="sub_heading">
        Contact me <span></span>
      </h1>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={sendEmail} ref={form}>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="email"
            required
          />
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="name"
            required
          />
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id=""
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using the suggested [react package](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/) as per the [official documentation](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/). I suggest you remove the one you are using and install the described one `@emailjs/browser` and do:

```
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
```

instead of your approach

```
import emailjs from "email-js";
```